# how can i get full repository path from SvnClient object?

Tags: sharpsvn

is there a way to get full path of repository from an svn object?
when i use .path or .pathRepository method i get only relative path of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SvnClient has a method GetRepositoryRoot which gives you the repository root URL. You can then combine this with the relative path of the file you get from .pathRepository.

Answer (score 4):

To get the the full uri to a file, use:

```
SvnInfoEventArgs info;
client.GetInfo(workingCopyPath, out info);
Console.WriteLine(info.Uri);
```

The repository root:

```
Console.WriteLine(info.RepositoryRoot);
```